# how can I use net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer in multiple threads to avoid impacting perfromance and throughput?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, xslt, saxon

In my project I am trying to use `net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer` in multiple threads using synchronization in java because as per documentation An XsltTransformer must not be used concurrently in multiple threads. It is safe, however, to reuse the object within a single thread to run the same stylesheet several times. Running the stylesheet does not change the context that has been established. Some of the public methods are synchronized: this is not because multi-threaded execution is supported, rather it is to reduce the damage if multi-threaded execution is attempted. but while trying to make stress test using JMeter by sending 100 request per second I found that `net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform()`  takes more time and sometimes reach to 6 mins.
How can I use `net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform()` in multiple threads without impacting performance?

I tried to make class TransformerSingleton as below

```
public class TransformerSingleton {

    private static XsltTransformer transformer;

    private TransformerSingleton() {

    }

    public static void xsltLoad() {

        if (transformer == null) {
            synchronized (XsltTransformer.class){
                try {
                    Processor processor = new Processor(false);
                    XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
                    XsltExecutable xslt = compiler.compile(new StreamSource("/my_path/"));
                    transformer = xslt.load();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static XsltTransformer getTransformer(){
        if (transformer == null) {
            synchronized (XsltTransformer.class) {
                xsltLoad();
            }

        } return transformer;

    }

}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        XsltTransformer transformer = XsltTransformerSingleton.getTransformer();
        String xml = "<Users><name>AAA</name></Users>"; // for example
        try (ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())) {
            synchronized (transformer){
           Transformer.setSource(new StreamSource(byteArrayInputStream));
            XdmDestination chainResult = new XdmDestination();
            Transformer.setDestination(chainResult);
            Transformer.transform();
            }
        }
    }
```

expected to make throughput reach to 100 requests per second.
actual I reached to 60 per second.

Comment: I would assume the use of synchronized in a singleton would hurt performance. Have you tested creating new instances every time? If that doesn't give the result you want, you could try using Java thread pool implementation.

Comment: The thread safe object is the XsltExecutable https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltExecutable.html so that is the one you can and only need to create once for each stylesheet you have, each thread or even each transformation can then create its own XsltTransformer or Xslt30Transformer from the shared XsltExecutable. Did you have any problems in terms of thread safety and/or performance using this approach or why do you want to reuse an XsltTransformer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to run the same stylesheet in parallel in multiple threads is to compile the stylesheet once into an `XsltExecutable`, and then create a new `XsltTransformer` for each transformation. Creating an `XsltTransformer` from an `XsltExecutable` is very cheap.